How can I calculate ROC50 in python?
I need to calculate ROC50 for a classifier in python. The ROC50 value is defined as the AUC when the 50th true negative is found. I have tried setting the max fpr value for roc_auc_score in sklearn to 50/ground truth negatives but I don't believe that is giving the correct score.
How can I calculate ROC50 in python?
Explanation of Terms:
ROC is the Receiver Operating Characteristics curve for a machine learning model that is formed when one plats the the TPR (True Positive Rate) against the FPR (False Positive Rate) for all probability predictions produced by the model. From that curve one can calculate the AUC (Area Under the Curve). A perfect classifier will have a AUC of 1.0 while a indiscriminate classifier will have a value of 0.5. ROC50 is the AUC for the data ranked by probability including only the data up until the 50th false positive occurs.

What is AUC? What is fpr? What is roc_auc_score and what are all the other terms you use here? You are assuming that we're all experts in exactly the kind of thing you want to do, but that's generally a poor assumption.

My apologies @WolfgangBangerth I thought since this is a computational science forum and I posted with the tags machine learning, AI and other related tags that all involve these metrics that most people seeking to answer here would be aware of those very common terms in both computational informatic and machine learning/AI.

ROC is the Receiver Operating Characteristics curve for a machine learning model that is formed when one plats the the TPR (True Positive Rate) against the FPR (False Positive Rate) for all probability predictions produced by the model.  From that curve one can calculate the AUC (Area Under the Curve).  A perfect classifier will have a AUC of 1.0 while a indiscriminate classifier will have a value of 0.5.  ROC50 is the AUC for the data ranked by probability including only the data up until the 50th false positive occurs.

I'm afraid the machine learning folks largely hang out on other forums :-(
